# Realm Database omitting a string when saving

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I'm having a problem when using Realm as my database.
I'm getting a token from my webservice and Realm is not saving it, when i get a response I get the token string, then after it's saved and I retrieve the user from the db it'll show the Token row as "null"
My original guess is that the token is too long to save it but I really don't know

Does everybody know anything about this?

I'll paste here my UserData class

```
public class UserData extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int userid;
    private int state;
    private int store;
    private String Token;
    private String user_name;
}
```

Comment: i think it's because you named it `Token` instead of `token`

Comment: What lenght of token string?

Comment: According to the guy that developed this, we can't know the size on the string(token) since it's size depends on the method that's generating it and the data I send to.

Comment: Can you show us the code which inserts `UserData` into your Realm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a guess (post the code for more help): It might be that you created the object, and used `copyToRealm`, but then added the token to the original object.

In that case, you need to [add the token to the result returned from `copyToRealm`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/), or requery the DB:

> When using `realm.copyToRealm()` it is important to remember that only the returned object is managed by Realm, so any further changes to the original object will not be persisted.